# Vue3 "v-is" component with varying element tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

The Vue3 documentation explains how to create a component that replaces e.g. a "tr" node, see [DOM template parsing caveats](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#dom-template-parsing-caveats).
The render function isn't shown, but I assume that it creates VDOM with a "tr" as top element.

In vue2 I could write such a component for varying elements, by accessing the data of the node that my component was supposed to replace. In the render function I could access the information of the node with the "v-is" as `this.$vnode.data`, especially the tag as `this.$vnode.data.tag`. So my component could adapt to the element that it was used for by creating a result with `h(this.$vnode.data.tag, ...)`.

This information (`this.$vnode.data`) does not seem to be available anymore in vue3. I looked at the render function's "this" and the global API for functions available in "render". No luck. Does anybody know how I can obtain this information in vue3?

Comment: `$vnode` was never in public/documented API. Maybe the smart thing to do is just pass an expected element by a prop ?

Comment: Doesn't really look smart: "<tr ... :tag="'tr'">

Comment: And, depending on undocumented API or using DOM templates does? It's safe and without suprises..

Comment: I'm looking for a solution; it doesn't have to rely on an undocumented API. It's not my fault that the Vue2 solution required an undocumented API.